# Is it possible to use JavaScript to change the GoogleAnalytics meta-tags of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meta-tags

This is my meta tag `<meta name="robots" content="none">`

and want to change this meta tag into

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

> ###### I am also trying to add meta tag by using this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.name = "robots";
    meta.content = "noindex";
    console.log(meta);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
});
```

But,it's not working

> SOLUTION

1. Go to `robots.txt` this page exist in your project
2. And `Disallow:/pagename`

and it will be worked

### `JavaScript` can't do anything in this, it is `SEO` question `sorry` for `troubling` you all

Comment: While Google is capable of interpreting JavaScript, I rather doubt that they would take into account such a "dynamic" change of the robots meta tag; it is probably more likely that they parse this once from the initial HTML.

Comment: It wouldn't have any effect as GA gets site info before you do any changes with your javascript.

Comment: I tried to change it using JavaScript, but it remains the same.

Comment: There are two ways to interpret this question. (1) *Can I change it?* — You can test this yourself. Open the developer tools in your browser and look at the Inspector. Has the value changed? If so, you can. (2) *Will Google respect such a change?* — questions about how Google reacts to code are generally non-programming [tag:seo] questions are are off-topic here for the reasons described in the description of that tag.

Comment: I got the solution there is a page robots.txt you can go there and 
Disallow:/path
and it will be worked